# Oracle missing initSID.ora

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, database-administration

I learning to use Oracle database, and I just installed Oracle Database 12c Release 2 on my Ubuntu 18.04.

I login as **sysdba** with this following command:

`sqlplus / as sysdba`

So far all thing working and I got this message:

```
Connected to an idle instance.
```

Now, I want to start my server with this following command:

```
SQL> STARTUP
```

But, the thing that make me confuse are I got this error message:

```
ORA-01078: failure in processing system parameters
LRM-00109: could not open parameter file '/u01/app/oracle/product/12/dbhome_1/dbs/initSID.ora'
```

I checking it out on that directory, and the **initSID.ora** was missing.

So, where I can find the missing file..?, how to fix it..?

Comment: You must have installed Oracle s/w (Instance) but not created the database.
Please follow the link: [How to create the Oracle database](https://www.dummies.com/programming/databases/how-to-use-the-database-configuration-assistant-dbca-to-create-databases-in-oracle-12c/)

Comment: you're right about tagging @a_horse_with_no_name  I wished the to tag the same, but confused then.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally I figure out this by following @Tejash----ORA-00980 [instructions](https://www.dummies.com/programming/databases/how-to-use-the-database-configuration-assistant-dbca-to-create-databases-in-oracle-12c/) to create a database.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an `SPFILE` in `/u01/app/oracle/product/12/dbhome_1/dbs` directory to be able to start the database by only using `STARTUP` command.

If there's no `SPFILE` then a `PFILE` should explicitly be specified with the `STARTUP` command as

`SQL> STARTUP PFILE=/u01/app/oracle/product/12/dbhome_1/dbs/initSID.ora`

assuming you have a `PFILE` named `initSID.ora` in that directory.

Comment: What if I don't have the `initSID.ora` file..?

because I got this when try to run your command:

`LRM-00109: could not open parameter file '/u01/app/oracle/product/12/dbhome_1/dbs/initSID.ora'
ORA-01078: failure in processing system parameters`

Comment: @Harvest1018 you should already have a file `init.ora` or `init<yourSID>.ora` after installation. Perhaps, you delete those file or directory. Moreover, it's recommended to create an `SPFILE` file from that `PFILE`.